# Why I receive this TypeERROR:'str' object is not callable, in python?

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I'm doing my first currency Convertor in python, only with two currencies,  and I don't understand why that doesn't work properly? I decide to define all in functions and then call them back, but that isn't working.
I'm doing it in portuguese.

**This is my code:**

```
from decimal import Decimal as dec


def menu_conv():
    print(" ")
    print("»»»»»»»»»»»»»»» Bem-vindo ««««««««««««««")
    print("»»»»»»»»»» Conversor de Moeda ««««««««««")
    print(" ")
    print("**** Selecione a conversao desejada ****")
    print(" ")
    print("********* 1. Euros -> Dólares **********")
    print("********* 2. Dólares -> Euros **********")
    print("*************** 3. Saír ****************")
    print(" ")


def opcao():
    opcao = int(input("Insira a sua opçao:  "))
    if opcao == 1:
        dolar()
    elif opcao == 2:   
        euro()
    else:
        nao()


def dolar():       
    print(" ")
    montante = dec(input("Qual o montante que deseja converter? €"))
    DOLAR = dec(1.39)
    cambioDolar = dec(montante / DOLAR)
    print(" ")
    print("O Valor em Dólares é: ${:.2f}".format(cambioDolar))
    print(" ")
    print("Deseja fazer nova conversao?")
    print(" ")
    opcao_txt()


def euro():
    print(" ")
    montante = dec(input("Qual o montante que deseja converter? $"))
    EURO = dec(1.39)
    cambioEuro = dec(montante / EURO)
    print(" ")
    print(" O Valor em Euros é: €{:.2f}".format(cambioEuro))
    print(" ")
    print("Deseja fazer nova conversao?")
    print(" ")
    opcao_txt()


def opcao_txt():             
    opcao = input("» S/N: ")
    if opcao == 'S'or's':
        menu_conv()
        opcao()
    else:
        nao()


def nao(): 
    print("Até à próxima!")
    exit()   


menu_conv()
opcao()
```

**This is the ERROR I get when I try to do other convertion:**

```
»»»»»»»»»»»»»»» Bem-vindo ««««««««««««««
»»»»»»»»»» Conversor de Moeda ««««««««««

**** Selecione a conversao desejada ****

********* 1. Euros -> Dólares **********
********* 2. Dólares -> Euros **********
*************** 3. Saír ****************

Insira a sua opçao:  1

Qual o montante que deseja converter? €1000

O Valor em Dólares é: $719.42

Deseja fazer nova conversao?

» S/N: s

»»»»»»»»»»»»»»» Bem-vindo ««««««««««««««
»»»»»»»»»» Conversor de Moeda ««««««««««

**** Selecione a conversao desejada ****

********* 1. Euros -> Dólares **********
********* 2. Dólares -> Euros **********
*************** 3. Saír ****************

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conversor_moeda.py", line 68, in <module>
    opcao()
  File "conversor_moeda.py", line 20, in opcao
    dolar()
  File "conversor_moeda.py", line 37, in dolar
    opcao_txt()
  File "conversor_moeda.py", line 57, in opcao_txt
    opcao()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: In `opcao_txt()` you first do `opcao = input("» S/N: ")` and then try to call it. Note that `if opcao == 'S'or's':` will always run, since the non empty string `'s'` is truthy.  You want `opcao.lower() == 's'` for example.

Comment: Thank's !This was also very useffull to solve the problem to! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in your function opcao_txt you have a string variable named opcao which is also a function. So when you call opcao() you're actually trying to call the string.

Answer (score 0):

In `opcao_txt` you created a local variable named `opcao`, which takes precedence. It has a string value. You then try to call it with calling syntax `()` and you get that error. Use a different name for the variable should fix it.